# How to Implement Mixup in Keras Sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have multi class target, and I'm trying to implement mixup technique in Keras sequence.

Without it, I get above 70%, but I get below 5% if I include the code below.

Could someone let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    ...
    x_batch, y_batch = self.mixup(x_batch, y_batch)
    ...
    return x_batch, y_batch

def mixup(self, x, y):
    n = x.shape[0]
    l = np.random.beta(self.alpha, self.alpha, n)
    x_l = l.reshape(n, 1, 1, 1)
    y_l = l.reshape(n, 1)

    x1 = x
    x2 = np.flip(x, axis=0)
    x = x1 * x_l + x2 * (1 - x_l)

    y1 = y
    y2 = np.flip(y, axis=0)
    y = y1 * y_l + y2 * (1 - y_l)
    return x, y
```

Comment: Do you have any sources or papers that you are trying to replicate? not sure if this is a coding error or simply a problem writing out equations

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in sequence instead of generator. https://github.com/yu4u/mixup-generator Also I got more ideas from this comment. https://github.com/yu4u/mixup-generator/issues/2

Comment: Your code seems to be doing what it is supposed to. Maybe your problem is outside mixup. Try using this sequence just commenting the `self.mixup` line to see if the problem is somewhere else.